# Checking condition which table to Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to Check the "refno" already present in Tbldelivery table, If "refno" is present, then it will insert in "Tbldeliverydetails" because "refno" is primary key in 1st table. Where i check the condition ?

Here is the code i wrote in C# :

```
protected void btndlysave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
    try
    {
        SqlCon.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbldelivery (refno,deliverdate,requestby,projectcode) values 
        (@refno,@deliverdate,@requestby,@projectcode)               WHERE not exists (select refno from Tblinkdelivery where refno = @refno)", SqlCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        if ( need check here)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refno", txtdelrefno.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliverdate", txtdeldate.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@requestby", txtdelreq.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projectcode", ddlprojcode.Text.Trim());
        }

        else
        {

        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Tbldeliverdetails (refno,printercode,inkcode,quantity,price,notes) values             (@refno,@printercode,@inkcode,@quantity,@price,@notes)", SqlCon);
        cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refno", txtdelrefno.Text.Trim());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@printercode", ddldelprcode.Text.Trim());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inkcode", ddlinkcode.Text.Trim());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", txtdelqty.Text.Trim());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtdelprice.Text.Trim());
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", txtdelnotes.Text.Trim());

        int val1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        int val2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        SqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this actually compile?  Looks like you commented out an if, and unless I am mistaken, there is no such thing as a try/else/finally block in C#.

Comment: try
            {
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select refno from Tblinkdelivery where refno ='" + txtdelrefno.Text + "'", SqlCon);
                var dt = new DataTable();
               da.Fill(dt);

               if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
               { All Codes }

Comment: I count the number of rows in the table.If the row is zero, the the code inside the "if" is executed another wise the code in "else" is executed. It is run Mr.Zoidberg

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you need to arrange your code.
Writing everything inside the `button click` event is not good at all. It is better if you can separate business logic and put it separately. 
Try something like this.
You can create `Data Access` class which handle your data access.
In your Data Access Class

```
public SqlConnection OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                var  conn = new SqlConnection(“xxx”);
                conn.Open();
                return conn;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log the exception
                return null;
            }
        }

YourFunction(parameters)
{
    var conn = OpenConnection();
    if(conn != null)
    {
        //your code
        // you can do something similar as JeremyK explained here 
    }

}
```

And in your button click

```
protected void btndlysave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CHECK THE PARAMETERS AND PASS
    //DataAccess. YourFunction(parameters)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You query the table and see if it exists.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = 
        new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Tbldelivery WHERE refno=@refno", 
                        connection);

    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@refno", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
    sqlCommand.Parameters["@refno"].Value = refnoValue;

    SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
    // refno exists
    }
    else
    {
    // refno does not exist
    }
}
```